# Simulating a curled phone wire in Unity

Tags: unity, simulations, maya, rope-physics

I'm made a model for a project at work (depicted in the image bellow) that requires me to create a somewhat realistic movement on a curled phone wire.

[image]

Here is what i have tried so far:
I've tried setting up a joint chain in Maya and skinning the mesh to the joints. I then un-parented all of the joints so that none of them are part of the same hierarchy. Then i imported the mesh into Unity, and added a character joint component to each of the joints. I then recreated the hierarchy from Maya by using the "connected body" function within the character joint components of each of the joints. Lastly I made colliders for each of the joints.

This procedure works as intended when I try to recreate the desired effect on a separate chain of individual spheres where each sphere gets its own joint, but on the wire everything is freaking out and the mesh practically explodes.
This leads me to believe that the problem is caused because the mesh is being skinned to multiple different joints that aren't part of the same hierarchy before specifying the hierarchy within unity.

Is there a way to use a regular joint hierarchy from Maya as to avoid avoid setting it up in Unity? Is it easier to maybe use cloth simulation? Is there another work around that I should try?

I mostly work within Maya so my work within unity is usually limited to model import, setup and assignment of materials and setting up animation controllers. This means that my Unity knowledge is pretty basic, and as such it'd appreciate it if the responses could be spelled out so that a newbie like me can understand it :)

Thanks so much in advance.